# Definitions of ''up above''

Tags: definition

I searched on Google the meaning of *up above*. I didn't find the answer (except *in heaven*, which is not the answer I was looking for). Here is the context: *Somewhere up above the stars*.

I wouldn't ask you this if I could find the answer. Thanks for giving me the definition.

Comment: Thanks for doing your research. And thanks for providing context. If you could provide more than one sentence, it might be easier to give a more precise "definition" of what the author means by *somewhere up above the stars.*

Comment: Somewhere up above the stars
The wreckage of a universe floats past
(Moving to Mars; Coldplay)

Comment: up above- it's an idiomatic usage

Answer (score 2):

Above means "higher than". Something above the stars is further away from the ground than the stars are.

Particularly if we talk about "up above" without saying above what, this is used as an indirect way to to refer to heaven in the Christian tradition.

If someone talks about something "up above the stars" they are likely also referring to heaven or at least to something spiritual since as far as verifiable physics is concerned there's nothing we can see in everyday life that's further away than the stars.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from in heaven,  it also means occurring in the air, airy, atmospheric, flying, etc. (Thesaurus).

Comment: In many languages, one word means both the skies and the heavens. In English, we can use both words, at least in the plural, to refer to the atmosphere.

Comment: In the context "somewhere up above the stars" I don't think any synonym related to air or the atmosphere is likely to apply. This answer isn't very helpful as it stands and your use of "etc." indicates to me you didn't take the time to write a complete answer.